# c++ a question about function 'new' that results in ina -nan.(ind)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
char* typein(char* text)
{
    int count=0;
    ifstream srcFile("in.txt", ios::in); 
    if (!srcFile)
    { 
        cout << "error opening source file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    char x;
    while (srcFile >> x)
    {        
        if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
            text[count] = x;
        else if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')
            text[count] = x + 32;
        else
            text[count] = ' ';
        count++;
    }
    srcFile.close();
    return text;
}
double cal1(double* all1,char* text)
{
    int t,count=0;
    while(all1[count])
    {
        t = all1[count] - 'a' ;
        count++;
        if (t >= 0 && t <= 25)
            all1[t]++;
        else
            all1[26]++;
    }
    all1[27] =count ;
    double p, cal1 = 0;
    for (t = 0; t <= 26; t++)
    {
        p = (all1[t] / all1[27]);
        all1[t] = p * log(p);
    }
    for (t = 0; t <= 26; t++)
    {
        cal1 -= all1[t];
    }
    return cal1;
}
int main()
{   
    char *text = new char[30000]();
    double *all = new double[28]();
    double t2,result1=0,result2=0;
    text = typein(text);
    result1 = cal1(all,text);
    cout <<result1 << endl;
    delete[] all;
    delete[] text;
    return 0;
}
```

from a period of code that calculate a double number ,instead of receiving a number from the result, I still got a “-nan.(ind)” which is not a number. Besides, I have used the function of double *all = new double28,but there is still no error or bugs showing up.

Comment: 1) "_instead of receiving a number from the result, I still got a “-nan.(ind)”_ "_but there is still no error or bugs showing up._" So, are there bugs, or not? If not, what are you asking about? Undesired result, is the thing, that is, commonly referred to, as a bug. 2) Did you step through your code with a debugger, while investigating the values of all variables, so you could see where the code did something, that you didn't expect?

Comment: Hint: `all` is of type `double*` while `cal1()` returns a `double`

Comment: @CinCout Why is that a problem? Functions can, and, typically do, take arguments of different types, than what they are returning.

Comment: Use a debugger to step thru the code. Check the value of `count`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop `while(all1[count])` never would be executed because all elements of array are zero.

Therefore `count` is zero, `all1[27]` is zero.

Therefore `p = all1[t] / all1[27]` is 0.0/0.0, which is NaN, so only value you able to write into array is NaN.